# native SQL query, getting max entry

Tags: sql

Imagine a table T with two fields `f1` and `f2`

Lets put some dummy values:

```
(1,2) , (1,3) , (1,4), (2,2), (4,1), (4,2)
```

I would like to retrieve the max value of `f2` for each `f1` namely I would like my query to return :

```
(1,4), (2,2), (4,2)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `group by` and aggregate function `max()`

```
select f1,max(f2)
from tab
group by f1
```

Links to more informations:

- [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- [MAX()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY` f1, which will aggregate the rows for each different value of f1:

```
SELECT f1, MAX(f2)
FROM T
GROUP BY f1
```